# Grub2 does not recognize multiple boot partitions with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on each

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I had Ubuntu 10.04 or 12.04 installed on three partitions of my 1T byte hard drive.

I decided to upgrade all three and downloaded and burned 14.04.1 to a DVD disk using Brasero for the burn process.  I had no problems with the burn process and selected Btrfs for the partition reformat.  They all installed to each partition I selected.

But on reboot, Grub2 goes right to the one on sda1.  I tried reinstalling Grub2, Grub Customizer, and Boot-Repair, but nothing I've used has addressed this issue, although I have gotten Grub to give me a choice menu between Ubuntu, Advanced options,and two instances of Memtest, although the Memtest options are now gone.

Can someone please tell me how to get multiple installs of 14.04 to live together in harmony?.

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. Do not know about BTRFS and what additional issues that may cause.